# How to add an event listener to an element which is located inside of a function in React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, addeventlistener

So, I have a React component, inside of a component I have a function - showCoinSearch, which sorts data, and then for the each object of sorted data creates an option element. I want to create a new function inside of this particular component which is going to handleClick. But the event listener is not working, I've tried to add handleClick and this.handleClick() - but React doesn't see this function...

```
export default class AddCoin extends Component { 
  handleClick(e) {
    console.log('HANDELED')
  }
  showCoinSearch(e) {
  //...someCode to sort data
     sortedData.forEach(object => {
  const option = document.createElement("option");
  //The Problem lies here
  //this.handleClick and handleClick are not working
  option.addEventListener("click", handleClick); // How to handleClick??
  option.value = object.currency;
  coinsList.appendChild(option);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not how you use React; you don't use `document.createElement("option")`, or add event listeners like that. What you're supposed to do is build a data structure in your state that reflects the entire state of the app / component, then write a render() method that is capable of turning that entire data structure into an HTML representation.

Comment: @ChrisG oh, I see, thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to start with this amazing tutorial:

https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html

It will show you how to think an app with ReactJS, it's gonna save you a lot of time.

Your code could be refactor to something like this:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class AddCoin extends Component { 
  // more on arrow functions: 
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions
  handleClick = e => {
    console.log('HANDELED')
    this.props.onClick(e.target.value) // im returning the click to the parent
  }

  render() {
    const { options } = this.props
    return(
      <select>
        {options.map(op => <option onClick={this.handleClick} value={option.value}>{option.text}</option>)}
      </select>
    )
  }
}
```

This assumes your component is being initialized in a parent component, receiving data from there, like this:

```
const options = [{value: 'value', text: 'text', ...}]

<AddCoint onClick={this.myParentOnClickFunction} options={options} />
```